# Can we add parameters to Json validation annonations?

Tags: java, json, validation

I am doing the json field validation as below :

```
    @Valid
    @NotEmpty(message="Id must not be empty")
    @Size(min=1, max=70, message="Id accepts max length of 70")
    private String Id;
    @Valid
    @NotEmpty(message="application must not be empty")
    @Size(min=1, max=8, message="application accepts max length of 8")
    private String application;
```

This is working fine
but now i have got another requirement where while validating the second field i need to pass the id as well to the message, stating this application message is coming for which id

Example : application must not be empty for id = 123
or
application accepts max length of 8 for id = 456

I am not sure if i can pass other attribute from model to the message
If you have any clue please comment

Comment: I have tried something like  ```@Size(min=4, max=4, message="application value should be of length 4 ${modelName.id}")``` but getting  "references an unknown property " error

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is only possible to get current validated value, and the values in the annotation methods(min, max, etc). If someone actually knows of a way, please feel free to correct me.

To achieve access to another property value, you would need custom validation annotation on the type level. I'll assume the class holding data is called `MyModel`. Annotation might look like this:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyModelApplicationSizeValidator.class)
public @interface MyModelApplicationSize {

    String message() default "default message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    int min() default 0;

    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

And the actual validator for this annotation:

```
import com.example.random.model.MyModel;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class MyModelApplicationSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyModelApplicationSize, MyModel> {

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private String msgFormat;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyModelApplicationSize constraintAnnotation) {
        this.min = constraintAnnotation.min();
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.max();
        this.msgFormat = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyModel model, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String value = model.getApplication();
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty() || value.length() < this.min || value.length() > this.max) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            String message = String.format(this.msgFormat, this.min, this.max, value, model.getId());
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind building error message with `String.format` is not the best way to do it, it's kind of brittle, you might actually need to implement it in another way, depending on your needs.

And `MyModel`, validated with the new annotation:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@MyModelApplicationSize(message = "application accepts min length of %d and max length of %d for val - %s with id - %s", min = 2, max = 7)
public class MyModel {

    @NotEmpty(message="Id must not be empty")
    @Size(min=1, max=70, message="Id accepts max length of 70")
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty(message="application must not be empty")
    @Size(min=1, max=8, message="application accepts min length of {min} and max length of {max} for val - ${validatedValue}")
    private String application;

    //getters and setters
}
```